# How to handle async/await calls inside a setTimeout() block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a process that runs at a specific interval, let's say it runs on the every 10th second of the minute. It is a recursive function so at the end of every 10 seconds, it will call itself. This is working so far.

Inside this timer function, I have an async/await call to an API. Basically what it does is, it makes the API call, gets the data and that data is pushed to a client once it is %100 complete.

The problem is that if that async/await call takes longer than the interval of my timer, I am starting to get overlaps.

So, this is a bit of a design question. I have found the solution by using a global variable inside my API call wrapper function.

```
var REQUEST_CYCLE_ACTIVE = false;
```

or

```
var REQUEST_CYCLE_ACTIVE = true;
```

Inside the timer, I can skip the recursion if the API call is unfinished and it will try on the next interval.

This works. But I am curios to know if there is a more elegant way to solve this. I am also providing an example `node.js` application which demonstrates the issue and the solution.

```js
// A simple function to simulate resource delays.
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Construct a time string for debug purposes.
const getTime = () => {
    var now = new Date();
    var h = now.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var m = now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var s = now.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const timeSignature = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
    return timeSignature;
}

// Update
// This is the request wrapper.
const update = async () => {
  REQUEST_CYCLE_ACTIVE = true;
  
  let result;
  try {
    result = await someFakeAPI();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  let timeSignature = getTime();
  console.log(`\t\t(REQUEST) update() is done. Here is the result:`);
  console.log('\t\t', result)
  
  // Once the data is %100 collected here (there are retries etc.)
  // we make a call to the websocket and force-push the data to all
  // of the connected clients.
  
  // PUSH TO CLIENTS()
  
  REQUEST_CYCLE_ACTIVE = false;
};

// The core mock API call function.
async function someFakeAPI() {
  // Emulate an asynchroneous fetch.
  console.log('\t\t(REQUEST) Fetching data ...')
  // 12000 miliseconds (12 sec) is longer than our timer call.
  // There will be an overlap.
  await delay(12000);
  let result = 0.6; // Change to 0.4 to trigger a failed fetch.
  if (result < 0.5) {;
    return '__FAIL__';
  } else {
    return {name: 'apple', price: '1234.12', time: 1549926859970};
  }
}

// Just an initial API call to get things started.
async function sendExchangeRequest()
{
  let result;
  try {
    result = await someFakeAPI();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  return result;
}

// runClock {{{1
const runClock2 = async () => {
  let next_update_seconds;
  // This is our interval, the recursive function will be called on every n'th second of the minute.
  // For example, an interval of 10 means, the calls will be placed at 22:11:00, 22:11:10, 22:11:20 etc.
  var interval = 10; //seconds
  var date = new Date();

  let current_seconds = date.getSeconds();

  let buffer = 60 % interval;
  let border = (60 - buffer);

  // Interval calculations.
  if (current_seconds <= border) {
    if ((current_seconds % interval) == 0) {
      next_update_seconds = interval;
    } else {
      let distance = (border - current_seconds);
      let slice = (distance % interval);
      next_update_seconds = slice;
    }
  } else {
    next_update_seconds = (60 - current_seconds);
  }
  
  let next_update_milliseconds = (next_update_seconds * 1000); 
  var timeToNextTick = (next_update_milliseconds);

  let timeSignature = getTime();
  console.log(`[4] <${timeSignature}> Starting runClock(), time to next Async REQUEST: ${timeToNextTick}ms`);

  setTimeout(function() {
    let timeSignature = getTime();
    console.log(`\t(${timeSignature}) Time is up, done waiting. Async REQUEST will be called.`);
    if(REQUEST_CYCLE_ACTIVE){
      console.log(`\t(${timeSignature}) Previous Async REQUEST already running. Skipping ...`);
    }else{
      console.log(`\t(${timeSignature}) Previous Async REQUEST is complete. Running a new one ...`);
      // MAKE THE ASYNC API CALL HERE.
      update();
    }
    // Recursion
    console.log(`\t(${timeSignature}) Start runClock() again.`);
    runClock2();
  }, timeToNextTick);
};

var REQUEST_CYCLE_ACTIVE = false;

(async () => {
  console.log('[1] Make the request:')
  try {
    response = await sendExchangeRequest();
    console.log('[2] Report the result:\n\t', response)
    console.log('[3] Start the clock cycle.');
    runClock2();
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('FAILED:', error)
  }
})();
```

If you have issues with the included code, here is the REPL link: [AsyncConcepts2.repl.run](https://repl.it/@cryptoeraser/AsyncConcepts2)

Finally, a gif demonstrating the example:
[image]

Comment: I did not want to await for the API call inside the timer cause there are bunch of other services running (websockets) etc, in the original project. So I was worried that the API request would block the other services. I need to have that API call happen in the background, without blocking the entire app. I just would like to make sure that the timer does not cause a pile up, cause once the API call is delayed, I get the overlap, which is nasty.

Comment: rather than using an interval, use a settimeout AFTER the response, to trigger the next "loop" ... `API request would block` asynchronous, so, non-blocking

Comment: Where exactly? I’m not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: It's not an answer it's a comment. Your response helps me understand your level of expertise

Comment: I am new to node and javascript. It is difficult for me to change the design at this stage. I know it is confusing to have an "interval" and a "window of data gathering". But that is another topic. I'm just trying to figure out if there is a more elegant way of having this hybrid solution.

Comment: there are different approaches possible depending on your need: you may cancel previous request; you may postpone sending new request until previous is finished; you may run next timeout only after response is retrieved; you may still process overlapping responses but ensure that older data is not overwrite newer data because of different delays

Comment: I guess it is a question with a broader design and implementation scope. Should I delete? Please up-vote this and I will delete it.